# laravel 5.6 request duplicate URL parameter

Tags: laravel, url, request

I am working on the locale translation and I am trying to get the parameter `en` from the below URL: `http://localhost/public/en`

I used `{{Request::segment(1)}}` to get the `en`. However, when I insert it back into `<a href="{{Request::segment(1)}}/training">`, the URL becomes:

`http://localhost/public/en/en/training` (which the `en` is duplicated)

However, I want to make the URL as

`http://localhost/public/en/training`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Add your relevant codes . It will help for solving your problem fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is much much much more elegantly solved with Route parameters.

So in your `web.php` (`routes.php` if you're running really old Laravel) you can specify a parameter:

```
Route::get('/public/{language}/training', 'PublicController@training');
```

Now the `en` in your route will be available as a parameter to your Controller:

```
class PublicController extends ApplicationController {
   public function training(Request $request, $language) {
      return view('training', ['language' => $language]);
   }
}
```

Now you're able to access the `en` value in your view or controller.

And you can use the link helper to build a link:

```
<a href="{{ action('PublicController@training', ['language' => 'en']); }}">Training - English</a>
```

Sources:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/urls#generating-basic-urls
2. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters